# How do I get the url parameter in a Flask view

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to get the url parameters from a flask view:

```
www.domain.com/?f=x**2
```

How do I get `x**2` from the `url` in a Flask view?

Comment: Regarding that question you just deleted: You could use a regular expression, and replace `([a-z]|\d+)(?=[a-z]|\d+)` with `\1*`. That would work for variables.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can retrieve query string variables using

```
request.args.get('myParam')
```

or

```
request.args['myParam']
```

Where `myParam` is the variable in the query string you're trying to receive.

Comment: and if you want to set a default value... `request.args.get('myParam', 'myDefaultValue')`