# Flask Restful: change representation based on URL parameter

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am building an API using Flask and Flask-Restful. The API might be accessed by different sort of tools (web apps, automated tools, etc.) and one of the requirement is to provide different representations (let's say json and csv for the sake of the example)

As explained in the restful doc, it's easy to change the serialization based on the content type, so for my CSV serialization I've added this:

```
@api.representation('text/csv')
def output_csv(data, code, headers=None):
    #some CSV serialized data
    data = 'some,csv,fields'
    resp = app.make_response(data)
    return resp
```

And it's working when using curl and passing the correct `-H "Accept: text/csv"` parameter.

The issue is that since some browsers might be routed to a url directly to download a csv file, I would like to be able to force my serialization via a url parameter for example `http://my.domain.net/api/resource?format=csv` where the `format=csv`would have the same effect as `-H "Accept: text/csv"`.

I've gone through both Flask and Flask-Restful documentation and I don't see how to correctly handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a sub-class of [`Api`](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.1/api.html#flask.ext.restful.Api) and override the [`mediatypes`](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.1/api.html#flask.ext.restful.Api.mediatypes) method:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotAcceptable

class CustomApi(Api):
    FORMAT_MIMETYPE_MAP = {
        "csv": "text/csv",
        "json": "application/json"
        # Add other mimetypes as desired here
    }

    def mediatypes(self):
        """Allow all resources to have their representation
        overriden by the `format` URL argument"""

        preferred_response_type = []
        format = request.args.get("format")
        if format:
            mimetype = FORMAT_MIMETYPE_MAP.get(format)
            preferred_response_type.append(mimetype)
            if not mimetype:
                raise NotAcceptable()
        return preferred_response_type + super(CustomApi, self).mediatypes()
```

Comment: just wondering: how do I use the CustomApi class? When I do: 
app = Flask(__name__)
api = CustomApi(app)
then it seems overridden mediatypes method is never used?

Answer (score -1):

Basically you want to retrieve parameters from GET method. Please refer to:
[How do I get the url parameter in a Flask view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026704/how-do-i-get-the-url-parameter-in-a-flask-view)